# Python multiprocessing corrupts dataframe in each process in the pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a function that takes some data into a dataframe, does some stuff to it, and then returns the final dataframe.

I have to do this for different nodes of a cluster setup with each node having different data. Thus, I am trying to parallelize it to save time.

However, there is a problem at the very end of the function. Specifically:

```
print(type(all_node_data)) # This gives a DataFrame type as it should
all_node_data = all_node_data.drop(all_node_data.columns[1], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(type(all_node_data)) # This gives a NoneType
```

the code I use to parallelize the function is this

```
pool = Pool(mp.cpu_count())
func = partial(myfunc, arg1, arg2)


data = pool.map(func, iterable)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The reason I use a partial is because each time I invoke the function, I want a different value from an iterable in one of the arguments.

Comment: Remove `inplace=True` (this leads to a `None` return).

Comment: Why would this be the case when multiprocessing? Because when I run a single instance of the function, it works fine?  

Could it be a problem with the memory?

Comment: Imho this has nothing to do with mulitprocessing. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) you'll find the follwoing: _"... **Returns**: **DataFrame or None** DataFrame without the removed index or column labels **or None if `inplace=True`**. ..."_ That is the usual behavoiur for inplace-functions.